# Storing Images on SQL With Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I created a web scraper on Node.js to search and download pictures for a project. The project requires more than 7000 pictures so I was planning to store them on mySQL(or SQLlite) but I am struggling to find a way to read and write to SQL using either JavaScript or Node.js.

Comment: you're struggling to find a way to do this bc its not a great idea. thats a heavy hit for a DB to manage...nowadays folks use CDNs to manage static assets like images.

Comment: @LostJon how would you suggest I do this, should I use python instead or is there another way altogether? Sorry I'm very new to this.

Comment: depends on your cloud provider, not your runtime; Im an AWS guy, so I use S3 to store my images and Cloudfront to serve them. Other folks may lean more towards Cloudflare or other cloud alternatives.